# get only 1 wpdb and get taxonomy, post to next page

Tags: wpdb

1st question.

```
 $passport_num="M00093";
  $querystr = "
SELECT $wpdb->posts.* 
FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta
WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id 
AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = '_Passport' 
AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = $passport_num
AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' 
AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'us_visa'
ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC
  ";


AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = $passport_num
```

This part is not working. how can I change it?

2nd question,

```
<div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
  <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>">
  <?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
  <small><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> <!-- by <?php the_author() ?> --></small>
  <div class="entry">
     <?php the_content('Read the rest of this entry »'); ?>
  </div>

  <p class="postmetadata">Posted in <?php the_category(', ') ?> | <?php edit_post_link('Edit', '', ' | '); ?>  
  <?php comments_popup_link('No Comments', '1 Comment ', '% Comments '); ?></p>
</div>
```

NO RESULT

I need to get a term from a taxonomy ("visa_processing") how can I get the term which is related with this post?

3rd question.

I put like this and got result. but I need to send it to next page as "POST" (we don't want to show them on URL with the taxonomy (term).

thanks for your time.

Comment: Please ask each separate question separately.

Answer (score 1):

For 1st question

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'us_visa',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'orderby' => 'post_date',
  'order' => 'DESC',
  'meta_query' => array(
     array(
       'key' => '_Passport',
       'value' => $passport_num,
     )
   )
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

See [Custom Field Parameters of WP_Query on Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters)

---

For 2nd question, inside the loop use

```
<?php the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'visa_processing', '<p>', ' / ', '</p>') ?>
```

See [the_terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_terms) docs on Codex

---

Sorry, I don't understand the 3rd Question.